# How to show error message in form validation after completing the user entering

Tags: forms, validation, angular, ionic2

I am working on form input field i am able to display errors if the user enters wrong.

What i am expecting is when after the user complete is text in the input field and after that i should get the error message.

but i am getting the error message shown when user started is typing

here is my html code

```
  <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()" >

    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label primary floating>
              FIRST NAME
            </ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" id="firstname" class="form-control" formControlName="firstname"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>

      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label primary floating>
              LAST NAME
            </ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" id="lastname" class="form-control" formControlName="lastname"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label primary floating>
        USER ID (PHONE NO)
      </ion-label>
            <ion-input type="number" id="useridphone" class="form-control" formControlName="useridphone"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <div *ngIf="submitAttempt">
    <p *ngIf="myForm.controls.useridphone.errors && myForm.controls.useridphone.dirty  " >
      <small class="up" > 
        <strong><i>
          Phone Number Must be 10 digits!
        </i></strong>
      </small>
    </p>
    </div>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label primary floating>
        PASSWORD
      </ion-label>
            <ion-input type="password" id="password"  class="form-control" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <p *ngIf="myForm.controls.password.errors && myForm.controls.password.dirty">
      <small class="up">
        <strong><i>
          Password must contain atleast (4),1-Char 1-Number
        </i></strong>
      </small>
    </p>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label primary floating>
        CONFIRM  PASSWORD
      </ion-label>
            <ion-input type="password" id="confirmpassword"  class="form-control" formControlName="confirmpassword" ></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label primary floating>
        EMAIL
      </ion-label>
            <ion-input type="email" id="email"  class="form-control" formControlName="email" ></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <p *ngIf="myForm.controls.email.errors && myForm.controls.email.dirty "  class="alert alert-danger">
      <small class="up">
        <strong> <i>
          Please Enter Valid Email Address!
        </i></strong>
      </small>
    </p>

    <div padding> </div>
    <div padding> </div>

    <button ion-button full round  type="submit" [disabled]="!myForm.valid" color="secondary">SIGN UP</button> <br>
  </form>
```

here is my ts file

```
passwordRegex: any = '(^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]+$)' ;
  emailRegex: any = '^[a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,15})$';

this.myForm =  new FormGroup({
      'firstname'      : new FormControl('',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(3),Validators.maxLength(10)]),
      'lastname'       : new FormControl('', [Validators.required,Validators.minLength(1),Validators.maxLength(10)]),
      'useridphone'    : new FormControl('', [Validators.required,Validators.minLength(10),Validators.maxLength(10)]),
      'password'       : new FormControl('',Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.minLength(4),Validators.maxLength(25),
                          Validators.pattern(this.passwordRegex)])),
      'confirmpassword': new FormControl('',Validators.required),
      'email'          : new FormControl( '', Validators.compose([ Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.emailRegex) ]) )
    })
```

Comment: You could implement this when the text field the user is typing in "loses focus". So the user clicks in the field and types, etc. When they leave the field (so the field loses focus), have a handler that runs the validation.

Comment: can you give me one expample for example i have written the `p` tag to get the error message  simmilar to that can you show one

Comment: Look up "onblur". It's a standard HTML event, just the opposite of "focus". There are TONS of examples.

Comment: with an example can you post an answer i will check it and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Use "onblur" event of HTML element.

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="value" onblur="validateText ( this )"/>
```

validateText will run when the user "leaves" the input field.

(User later indicated this was Ionic specific).

onBlur is (as far as I can see) an open issue in Ionic. It doesn't work. The recommendation from the github thread on this:

Here is a current work around for "blur".

Use "focusout" or "mouseleave". Those are both working.

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/5487

Note that in the github thread, it says that post beta-4 of Ionic, "blur" is working.

Comment: but in ionic 2 i am not able to use this one

Comment: https://www.joshmorony.com/advanced-forms-validation-in-ionic-2/ check this link i have tried the same one also but not able to get the output  but the demo shows the exact output that i needed

Comment: `mouseleave` would be a very bad solution, what happens when people tab through the forms? On top of that does this answer not use any of the `Validator` objects and totally refrains from using the `FormGroup`. Not an answer in my opinion.

Comment: I agree that if Ionic does not properly implement onblur, that's bad. But this is the recommended workaround straight from the team, it's not "my" answer. Note also the answer mentions "focusout" not just "mouseleave". I additionally reference the github thread where the recommendation is made. Note also that "beta 4" of Ionic seems to address the issue.

Comment: Yep, but currently there have been beta's till beta.12 (released September), RC.0 -> RC.5 and yesterday the final version for `ionic 2.0.0` so the chance of Mohan Gopi using a version below beta-4 is almost null. *Also because I've seen some of his other questions before*

Comment: Well, then again, the recommendation for prior-beta 4, and the github thread I point at which links out to the solution post beta-4, all provided by the Ionic team, should provide everything needed.